# Can I rent a car in Berlin and drive to Krakow?

Tags: germany, car-rentals, poland, berlin, krakow

We have 5 people traveling from Berlin to Krakow and want to know if this is a reasonable way to travel?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? [It's just a 5.6 hour drive](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Berlin,+Germany/Krakow,+Poland/@51.2620685,14.6890037,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a84e2b719cf2f3:0x8dba8fa58c57d186!2m2!1d13.4552919!2d52.4938053!1m5!1m1!1s0x471644c0354e18d1:0xb46bb6b576478abf!2m2!1d19.9449799!2d50.0646501!3e0).

Comment: Please see this [question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29131/how-to-rent-a-car-for-a-europe-road-trip/29160#29160). You can only use the big four (Avis, Hertz, Europcar, Sixt).

Comment: Do you have specific concerns? Do you want to know how it compares to other options, price-wise or otherwise? Are you afraid it would not be allowed at all?

Comment: AFAIK, significant problem might be finding place to park the car in Kraków.

Comment: EU drivers license would enhance chances ;)

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely.

It's just a short ride, 5½-6 hours. As for quality of the roads, in both in Germany as well as in Poland you'll be riding top quality freeway practically all the way. They are basically equivalent to US Interstate Highways.

In Germany it's [Bundesautobahn 15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesautobahn_15) (Federal Freeway 15), in Poland short part [A18](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A18_autostrada_(Poland)), then [A4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A4_autostrada_(Poland)). All of which are recently (re-)built. 
[image]

You don't even have to worry about snow or ice in the winter, these freeways are part of one of the main pan-European routes, they're considered priority one for deicing.

Keep in mind that the only reasonable option for parking in Kraków will be paid underground parking, which should cost you around 50zł (about $16) per day.

Comment: Based on Google street view, A4 looks better than most US interstates I've been on.

Answer (score 1):

Define "reasonable".
The distance isn't a problem, road conditions shouldn't be either (but don't expect US style superhighways) except some parts maybe in winter (snow and icing).

It's *possible* that there could be rental agencies disallowing entry in their vehicle into Poland due to [some reports of car theft gangs operating out of there](http://www.economist.com/blogs/charlemagne/2013/09/crime-germany), but I seriously doubt it's much of an issue any longer. (It's not clear if it's still an issue, and most of the reporting on this problem suggested the cars were stolen outside Poland, then trucked there later for disassembly).

So there's no reason you shouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: It's still an issue with Eastern Europe, at least with more expensive cars. Else +1.

Comment: I'd just ask at bigger companies as Sixt, Hertz, Eurocar... They wil have some offer I'm sure.

Comment: -1 for repeating xenophobic propaganda. Poland has one of the lowest car theft rates in all EU, with only 42.5 car thefts per 100K people. By comparison Italy has 322.9, Sweden 304.1, the Netherlands 119.2, Germany 85.2.

Comment: @andra: he knows that, because Geert Wilders told him :-P

Comment: @vartec: That's what jwenting said. Nobody steals cars in Poland.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's not what “disallowing entry into Poland in their vehicles (crime statistics...)” suggests…

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the bigger car rental companies. Usually you can rent a car in Germany and return it in Poland. Then stay for some days and get a car to return to Germany. Shouldn't be a problem in every bigger city.

You need a drivers license that is valid in the EU!